Regex to check for a combination of character number and character
I need to check the first 3 letters of  my postal code field.
This has to be either 3 digit number or a combination of CNC (character, Number, Character)
Can anyone please help me with the regex expression for the same?
I want to use the same in the below Function.
REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME, ‘[^a-zA-Z]+’)


This has to be either 3 digit number or a combination of CNC (character, Number, Character) => ([0-9]{3}|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]) and maybe also anchored

I think something like this should be able to do the job:
REG_MATCH(POSTAL_CODE, '^(?:\d{3}|[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z])')


your regexp is
^([A-Z][0-9][A-Z]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])


I think this might work. Let you give it a try.
REG_MATCH(POSTAL_CODE, '^(?:\\d{3}|[A-Za-z]\\d[A-Za-z])')


^ asserts that the match starts at the beginning of the string.
(?: ... ) is a non-capturing group, allowing you to match either
\d{3}: exactly three digits.
[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z]: a pattern with a letter, a digit, and another letter (case-insensitive).

